# How to replace characters which have alternate meanings in strings. This code works, but creates errors

Tags: string-manipulation

**The Problem:  I often paste strings into Mathca which have many what I call "extender characters" --which may extend the character set."**  We know these have to be dealt with  so Mathca can deal with the string without error.

**Here is an example of such a string.**  The "extender characters" are the \ characters.  (Happens to be a directory string pasted from W7.)

```
myString=
"C:\Users\NEW USER\Documents\Data Files General\Creative Write\Analysis incl Econ Trips etc\Write Econ Soc Chce Fin Trips\Mathca\Learn and How Tos\Projcts Apps Unoptimized\Gradebook12x3x12plus.nb"
```

**Here is code which converts myString into something more clear to Mathca:**

```
    FromCharacterCode[
       Insert[ToCharacterCode[
          myString],92,
          Position[ToCharacterCode[myString],92]]]  (* 92 is the ascii code of \ *)
```

The code works It replaces all "\" by "\\".
But it generates many "Unknown string escape" errors (warning that the \ characters in the string enable the extended character set, etc.)

**There needs to be (there must be!) a function** which permits us to optionally suppress the control character potentiality of certain characters.  Then I would simply enter:

```
ConstrainedString[myString,{list of characters to optionally constrain}]
```

Then I could use

```
ReplaceAll[myConstrainedString, "\"->"\\"]
```

I don't want to be blindsided by extender characters not relevant in my code if, in that code, those characters only have the literal meaning.  I want a clean way of converting or manipulating strings which have "extender characters", so a longer list of functions will be available.

Comment: Shouldn't Mathematica offers to escape the pasted string for you? Like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/3oEHh.gif).

Comment: @Silvia well that only works on a front-end, and not if working directly in the kernel or on Wolfram Engine. In the kernel `StringReplace["\a\b\c", "\\" -> "\\\\"]` complains that these are `Syntax::stresc: Unknown string escape`.

Comment: @rhermans I would argue `"\a\b\c"` is a syntax error at the beginning. Or maybe it boils down to whose responsibility it is to differentiate `"\a"` (two characters) and `"\n"` (one character): should kernel tries to be smart or should users differentiate them when construct the string?

Answer (score 2):

A somewhat simpler method would be to use `StringReplace` to change the single backslash `\` into double backslashes `\\`. Each needs to be "escaped" (doubled) in order to work.

```
StringReplace[myString, "\\" -> "\\\\"]
```

It's not clear if this solves the "Unknown string escape" errors.

Comment: Why does each need to be escaped (doubled). I never thought of that...

Comment: The backslash indicates that the next character is special. So to get an actual backslash inside the quote, you have to indicate that the backslash is actually a backslash (and not the special escape character), which is done by doubel-backslash. This is a particular example of an escape character http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character