# Why does the string "\" prevent a graph6 string conversion to a graph?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, import

I input the graph6 string `` ihChWC@?gE_@?@?A_@g?@??C??j?@l??E??Ao??\???m??@I??DF??E`O??GM??@?g??S\@o?@g@O??G?w??C?I??D?@o?@g?D???_?M??@??I??D??FK?E_?@Q??G??N??@???CPCOaG\a?? ``
into  [houseofgraphs](https://houseofgraphs.org/draw_graph), and it looks good.

[image]

But when I use **ImportString**, it looks not good.

```
ImportString["ihChWC@?gE_@?@?A_@g?@??C??j?@l??E??Ao??\???m??@I??DF??E`\
O??GM??@?g??S\@o?@g@O??G?w??C?I??D?@o?@g?D???_?M??@??I??D??FK?E_?@\
Q??G??N??@???CPCOaG\a????", "Graph6"]
```

**Import::fmterr: Cannot import data as Graph6 format.**

I guess the character \ may be causing an issue. So I add another \ after each of them.

```
s = ImportString[
  "ihChWC@?gE_@?@?A_@g?@??C??j?@l??E??Ao??\\???m??@I??DF??E`O??GM??@?\
g??S\\@o?@g@O??G?w??C?I??D?@o?@g?D???_?M??@??I??D??FK?E_?@Q??G??N??@???\
CPCOaG\\a????", "Graph6"]
```

Now it works.

[image]

I'm a bit **concerned** that making this change **will also change the information of the input graph**, even if it does indeed get read. Interestingly, if we save the problematic graph6 string to a .g6 file, there are no issues whatsoever. I'm not sure **what the function `Import` is doing**. Is it also performing the same processing as I am, adding another \ after each \ in the string?

```
Import["G:/Graph.g6"]
```

[image]
So I'm wondering what exactly is happening behind the scenes here?

Comment: Backslash is an [escape character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character). It indicates that the character following it should be treated differently, for example "\n" denotes a new line, "\t" a tab and so on. But if you want an actual backslash in a string, it has to be escaped itself, ie. "\\". A dialog box appears when you paste a string containing a backslash in Mathematica which gives you an option of automatic conversion. Otherwise, see for example [Q1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/39650/75628) and ...

Comment: ... [Special Characters in String](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/StringsAndCharacters.html#11857).

Comment: @Domen Thank you. Besides this, are there any other characters that might cause an escape meaning, similar to \?